# If isogenous elliptic curves have equal numbers of points, how can isogenies have non-trivial kernels?

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Consider:

- Silverman, Ex V.5.4: Elliptic curves $E/\mathbb{F}_q$ and $E'/\mathbb{F}_q$ are isogenous if and only if $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q) = \# E'(\mathbb{F}_q)$.
- Silverman, **Proposition 4.12**: any finite subgroup $\Phi \subset E$ induces an isogeny $E \rightarrow E'$, where $E'$ has group structure $E / \Phi$.
- Silverman **Theorem 2.3**: Any non-constant morphism of curves is surjective.

Why do these three facts not contradict each other? In other words, if by quotienting with some nontrivial subgroup $\Phi \subset E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ I can induce a surjective isogeny $E \rightarrow E'$, why doesn't $E'$ have strictly fewer rational points than $E$? This is blowing my mind. Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at isogenies of the complex torus $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ with $\Lambda = \mathbf{Z} +  i \mathbf{Z}$ ? Those are of the form $z + \Lambda \mapsto z + \Lambda'$ with $\Lambda'$ a lattice containing $\Lambda$, which is the same as $z +\Lambda\mapsto z+H+\Lambda$ where $H$ is (a set of representatives of) $\Lambda'/\Lambda$ which is the kernel of the isogeny. Looking at the Weierstrass functions of $\Lambda,\Lambda'$ helps too, as $\wp_{\Lambda'}(z) = \sum_{a \in H} \wp_\Lambda(z+a)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surjective means here surjective from $E(\overline k)$ to $E'(\overline k)$
where $\overline k$ is the algebraic closure of $k=\Bbb F_q$. The image of
$E(k)$ may be a proper subgroup of $E'(k)$. There may be points $Q\in E'(k)$
which are images of elements of $E(\overline k)$ all lying outside $E(k)$.

Comment: thank you, but what about this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980399/to-show-a-morphism-of-affine-k-varieties-which-is-surjective-on-closed-points-is

Comment: The closed points in this definition correspond to Galois orbits on $E(\overline k)$. @BD107

Comment: Ah... so even a closed point of $E$ could reside in $E(\overline k) - E(k)$?