# Orders of isogenous curves over the algebraic closure

Tags: elliptic-curves, morphism, isogeny

Let $E/k$ and $E'/k$ be isogenous over $k$.

We know:

- $E$ and $E'$ are isogenous if and only if $\# E(k) = \# E'(k)$ [Ex V.5.4, Sil86].
- Any non-constant morphism of curves is surjective [Thm. II.2.3, Sil86].
- The kernel of an isogeny can have more that one points in it, which means that the map may not be injective.

First, I didn't understand how $E$ and $E'$ have same number of points, but the isogeny between them is surjective and not injective.

In this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2969598/1289848), it's made clear with the answer

> Surjective means here surjective from $E(\bar k)$ to $E′(\bar k)$ where $\bar k$ is the algebraic closure of $k$.

Does this mean that if $E/k$ and $E'/k$ are isogenous over $k$, the orders of $E(\bar k)$ and $E'(\bar k)$ might not be equal and the first one may be larger than the second?

PS: I'm not from math background and I humbly try to learn about isogenies.

[Sil86] *Silverman, Joseph H.*, [**The arithmetic of elliptic curves**](https://oeis.org/A127309), Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 106. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag. XII, 400 p. DM 148.00 (1986). [ZBL0585.14026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0585.14026).

Comment: $E(\overline k)$ and $E'(\overline k)$ will be infinite! So a surjective map can have a kernel.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you @Mathmo123